# Haskell Formatting Issue

Tags: haskell

```
main :: IO ()
main = do 
    contents <- readFile "text.txt"
    let database = (read contents :: [Film])
    putStr "Please enter your username: "
    userName <- getLine
    menu database        
    where menu newDb = do putStrLn "\nPlease select an option:"
                          putStrLn "1: Display all films currently in the database"
                          putStrLn "2: Add a new film to the database"
                          putStrLn "3: Search for films by director"
                          putStrLn "5: Exit"
                          putStr "\nSelected option: "
                          option <- getLine
                          case option of 
                                        "1" -> putStrLn(formatDatabase newDb)
                                        "2" -> do putStr "Name of film: "
                                               title <- getLine
                                               putStr "Name of director: "
                                               director <- getLine
                                               putStr "Year of release: "
                                               year <- getLine
                                               putStrLn(formatDatabase $ addFilm title director (read year) [] newDb)
                                        "3" -> do putStr "Name of director: "
                                               director <- getLine
                                               putStrLn $ formattedByDirector director
                          menu newDb
```

Returns error:

```
Parse error in pattern: putStr

On the line: "2" -> do putStr "Name of film: "
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must indent the lines in the `do` block all to the level of the first token *after* the `do`. The same applies to the case 3.

```
case option of 
  "1" -> putStrLn(formatDatabase newDb)
  "2" -> do putStr "Name of film: "
            title <- getLine
            putStr "Name of director: "
            director <- getLine
            putStr "Year of release: "
            year <- getLine
            putStrLn(formatDatabase $ addFilm title director (read year) [] newDb)
  "3" -> do putStr "Name of director: "
            director <- getLine
            putStrLn $ formattedByDirector director
```

Comment: This didn't resolve the issue, I still have the same error: Parse error in pattern: putStr

Comment: are you using tabs ? I read that 8 spaces tabs are assumed if that's the case. Maybe that's the source of your error.

Comment: @JamieB Must be something like Mog said, parses fine here.

Comment: I tried copying and pasting what you had, I tried deleting the info, this is it - http://imgur.com/yJuoQ

Comment: I confirm that you have tabs in your code (at least in what you posted in your OP). Try replacing ALL YOUR TABS by spaces. Should run fine.

Comment: @JamieB That _looks_ correctly indented. But you never know with tabs, don't use tabs in Haskell code, configure your editor to indent with spaces.

Comment: Where are you seeing the tabs?

Comment: BTW I suggest you tune your editor so that it uses spaces to simulate tabs (it's easily done in Notepad++). This way you won't be bothered later on. You can apply this behaviour only to .hs files quite easily if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @JamieB In your question, in several lines of code, there are tabs. Oh, and don't use screenshots to show your code, paste it at [hpaste](http://hpaste.org) or some similar service.

Comment: @JamieB: In Notepad++, turn on 'View -> Show Symbol -> Show White Space and TAB' and you'll see the tabs as arrows. If you want to turn them off, the option is under 'Settings -> Preferences', on the tab 'Language menu/TAB settings'; you need to check 'Replace by space'. To get rid of the tabs you already have, use 'Edit -> Blank Operations -> TAB to space'. By the way, I'm using Notepad++ 6.0 (but it works similarly in 5.9.x) and thanks for reminding me to turn them off in my new install :-)

Answer (score 0):

Please do not indent your code in the manner found in many textbooks. It looks nice on paper, but is terrible for actually working with.

Here's a much more sane style guide: https://github.com/tibbe/haskell-style-guide